# Operator >> can not be applied to operand of type char and long

Tags: java, c#

Am trying to convert java code to c# code. I got this error

> Operator >> can not be applied to operand of type char and long.

Code is:

```
static int getPruningP(byte[] table, long index, long THRESHOLD)
{
    if (index < THRESHOLD)
    {
        return tri2bin[table[(int)(index >> 2)] & 0xff] >> ((index & 3) << 1) & 3;
    }
    else {
        return tri2bin[table[(int)(index - THRESHOLD)] & 0xff] >> 8 & 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the type of `tri2bin`?

Comment: Error message is self explanatory. What do you try to do exactly?

Comment: Is it `java` or `c#`? Remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. tri2bin is char array. static char[] tri2bin = new char[243];

Comment: Am trying to covert source code in Java to c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `long` parameter to an `int` before doing the bitwise and.
Use

```
return tri2bin[table[(int)(index >> 2)] & 0xff] >> (((int)index & 3) << 1 ) & 3;
```

instead of

```
return tri2bin[table[(int)(index >> 2)] & 0xff] >> ((index & 3) << 1) & 3;
```

[*Binary & operators* are predefined for the integral types and `bool` and the & operator evaluates both operators regardless of the first one's value.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)

Therefore you need matching types for your *& operator*, currently you do `long & int`.

Comment: t has nothing to do with the '&' or shift operator - it's fine to combine 'long' and 'int' with the bitwise operators.  You just need to cast the return values.  Your solution works because the cast on 'index' changes the return value to an 'int', but the most direct solution is to cast the entire return value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it has nothing to do with the '&' or shift operators - the function returns 'int' and the result of the return statements is 'long', so you need to cast the return values:

```
static int getPruningP(byte[] table, long index, long THRESHOLD)
{
    if (index < THRESHOLD)
    {
        return (int)(tri2bin[table[(int)(index >> 2)] & 0xff] >> ((index & 3) << 1) & 3);
    }
    else {
        return (int)(tri2bin[table[(int)(index - THRESHOLD)] & 0xff] >> 8 & 3);
    }
}
```